# iBeacon android notfication with multiple regions

Tags: android, notifications, ibeacon, region, ibeacon-android

I just started with Java and Android coding. I wrote an application for a scientific study in my university. The app is for a local exhibition of a museum. I have different locations in my town, each location with its own exhibit.

Now I made an activity for each of the locations, so the user can see some useful information of the sample. Now I want to combine the app with iBeacons, I bought 6 beacons from Estimote. 
I want the app to give the user a notification with some text like: "You are in front of object XY. Tap to see more information." After tapping on the notification the user should open the specific activity which I created. I also want the app to search for beacons in the background, so if the user comes close to a location, he/she gets automatically a notification after a few seconds.

I already wrote some code but I don't know how to approach further. The application does nothing right now. 
I did an extra class for the iBeacon stuff, in my MainActivity I have a menu in which the user can select a new activity, which is called "List Of Places". Then s/he can select the specific activity for each of the locations.

So here I have my beacon class:

```
package com.example.walter.him;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Application;
import android.app.NotificationManager;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.app.TaskStackBuilder;
import android.support.v4.app.NotificationCompat;
import org.altbeacon.beacon.BeaconConsumer;
import org.altbeacon.beacon.BeaconManager;
import org.altbeacon.beacon.BeaconParser;
import org.altbeacon.beacon.Identifier;
import org.altbeacon.beacon.Region;
import org.altbeacon.beacon.powersave.BackgroundPowerSaver;
import org.altbeacon.beacon.startup.RegionBootstrap;
import org.altbeacon.beacon.startup.BootstrapNotifier;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;


public class BeaconMain extends Application implements BootstrapNotifier
{

private static final String TAG = "AndroidProximityReferenceApplication";
private RegionBootstrap regionBootstrap;
private BackgroundPowerSaver backgroundPowerSaver;
private boolean haveDetectedBeaconsSinceBoot = false;
private andreasplatz monitoringActivity = null;
private hagentor monitoringActivity2 = null;

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate();

    BeaconManager beaconManager = org.altbeacon.beacon.BeaconManager.getInstanceForApplication(this);
    beaconManager.getBeaconParsers().add(new BeaconParser().setBeaconLayout("m:2-3=0215,i:4-19,i:20-21,i:22-23,p:24-24"));
    beaconManager.bind((BeaconConsumer) this);
    Region museumLocation1 = new Region("museumLocation1",  Identifier.parse("B9407F30-F5F8-466E-AFF9-25556B57FE6D"), Identifier.parse("56170"), Identifier.parse("42307"));
    Region museumLocation2 = new Region("museumLocation2",  Identifier.parse("B9407F30-F5F8-466E-AFF9-25556B57FE6D"), Identifier.parse("55787"), Identifier.parse("12089"));
    List regionList = Arrays.asList(new Region[]{museumLocation1, museumLocation2});
    regionBootstrap = new RegionBootstrap(this, regionList);
    backgroundPowerSaver = new BackgroundPowerSaver(this);
}


public void didEnterRegion(Region region) {

    if (region.getUniqueId().equals("museumLocation1")) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, andreasplatz.class);
        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        this.startActivity(intent);
    }
    if (region.getUniqueId().equals("museumLocation2")) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, hagentor.class);
        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        this.startActivity(intent);
    }
    haveDetectedBeaconsSinceBoot = true;
}

@Override
public void didExitRegion(Region region) {

}

@Override
public void didDetermineStateForRegion(int i, Region region) {

}


private void sendNotification() {
    NotificationCompat.Builder builder =
            new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                    .setContentTitle("Beacon Reference Application")
                    .setContentText("An beacon is nearby.")
                    .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher);

    TaskStackBuilder stackBuilder = TaskStackBuilder.create(this);
    stackBuilder.addNextIntent(new Intent(this, andreasplatz.class));
    PendingIntent resultPendingIntent =
            stackBuilder.getPendingIntent(
                    0,
                    PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT
            );
    builder.setContentIntent(resultPendingIntent);
    NotificationManager notificationManager =
            (NotificationManager) this.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    notificationManager.notify(1, builder.build());
}

public void setMonitoringActivity(andreasplatz activity) {
    this.monitoringActivity = activity;
}
}
```

The activity "andreasplatz" would be an exemplary location. The activity "hagentor" has the same code in it. So here is the code for it:

```
package com.example.walter.him;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.os.Bundle;
import org.altbeacon.beacon.BeaconManager;

public class andreasplatz extends Activity {

    protected static final String TAG = "MonitoringActivity";
    private BeaconManager beaconManager;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_andreasplatz);
        verifyBluetooth();
    }



    private void verifyBluetooth() {

        try {
            if (!BeaconManager.getInstanceForApplication(this).checkAvailability()) {
                final AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
                builder.setTitle("Bluetooth not enabled");
                builder.setMessage("Please enable bluetooth in settings and restart this application.");
                builder.setPositiveButton(android.R.string.ok, null);
                builder.setOnDismissListener(new DialogInterface.OnDismissListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onDismiss(DialogInterface dialog) {
                        finish();
                        System.exit(0);
                    }
                });
                builder.show();
            }
        }
        catch (RuntimeException e) {
            final AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
            builder.setTitle("Bluetooth LE not available");
            builder.setMessage("Sorry, this device does not support Bluetooth LE.");
            builder.setPositiveButton(android.R.string.ok, null);
            builder.setOnDismissListener(new DialogInterface.OnDismissListener() {

                @Override
                public void onDismiss(DialogInterface dialog) {
                    finish();
                    System.exit(0);
                }

            });
            builder.show();

        }

    }


}
```

What should I add or change, to do the app what I want? Here s an extract of my Manifest.xml - may be I did something wrong in it:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0"
    package="com.example.walter.him" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="18"
        android:targetSdkVersion="18" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
        android:launchMode="singleInstance" >
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
```

Comment: Does the didEnterRegion method get called?

Comment: How do I find out? When I launch the application on my smartphone nothing happens...I get neither a notification nor the activity "andreasplatz" starts in the near of a beacon. But when I try to manually open the activity through the normal menu I get the message "MuseumApp stopped working".
Did I correctly choose the identifiers? I took the Major and the Minor ID

Answer (score 1):

A few tips:

1. Since you are using the `RegionBootstrap` you do not need to make a call to bind to the `beaconManager`.  Remove this line:

   ```
   beaconManager.bind((BeaconConsumer) this);
   ```
2. Add debug lines to the top of your `BeaconMain` class' `onCreate` and `didEnterRegion` methods like this:

   ```
   // put this at the top of onCreate
   Log.d(TAG, "onCreate called"); 

   // put this at the top of didEnterRegion
   Log.d(TAG, "didEnterRegion called with: "+region..getUniqueId());
   ```
3. Make sure your beacons are transmitting those identifiers.  Use an off the shelf beacon detector app like [Locate](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.radiusnetworks.locate&hl=en) when your beacons are turned on and make sure you see the same identifiers:

   ```
   B9407F30-F5F8-466E-AFF9-25556B57FE6D 56170 42307
   B9407F30-F5F8-466E-AFF9-25556B57FE6D 55787 12089
   ```
4. Once you have done the above, turn off your beacons, kill your app from the task switcher, re-launch your app, and turn on the beacons.
5. Watch the LogCat output and look for debug lines telling you if onCreate and didEnterRegion are called.

Comment: Okay, thanks. How can I test this in Android Studio? I am using GenyMotion, but it always shows "No bluetooth adapter". So I cannot see if the methods get called...

Comment: You cannot test in an emulator.  You must use a physical device with Bluetooth LE and Android 4.3+ to detect beacons.

Comment: Okay, I tried this, but where I can see then the LocCat? It's exactly the same like before. When I launch the app nothing happens. What I also noticed is that the app does not ask to turn the bluetooth on.

Comment: You need to manually turn on bluetooth oir your device will not detect beacons.  To learn how to debug Android programs and use LogCat, see here: https://developer.android.com/tools/debugging/debugging-studio.html#runDebug

Comment: So, after long trying to setup my device to the computer, I could see the logcat, but none of the logs which I put in the code appeared there. I am desperate. May be I am doing something wrong with the splitting of the code. My main acitvity does not contain any code, that has to do with the beacon stuff. I created just this class BeaconMain  - put there the code you provided, edited my Mainfest.xml and also added code to the activity I want to start after getting the notification. Would it be useful if I upload my whole project to GitHub?

Comment: Setting up a beacon-enabled app can be a bit daunting for folks that are new to Android programming.  Rather than starting from scratch as you have tried, a better idea may be to use the free an open source reference application as a starting point, then modify it to suit your needs: https://github.com/altbeacon/android-beacon-library-reference

Comment: Okay, I think you could be right. But as I said I already did the app with all the content that I need. The only thing I need, the beacon related code. So do I have to call the Beacon stuff in my main activity?

Comment: The manifest file needs to have `<application android:name="com.example.walter.him.andreasplatz"` element, otherwise your Application class will not be used.  Try adding that and putting `Log.d` statements in `onCreate` and `didEnterRegion` and make sure they are getting called.

Comment: This stuff is already in the code, I just posted the upper part of my manifest.xml. And as I said in the post before, the methods are not getting called. My MainActivity is set as the launch activity in the manifest. In your application you have the monitoring activity as the launch activity... may be something with it?

Comment: To be clear, you must have the `android:name="com.example.walter.him.andreasplatz"` entry in the application declaration.  This is missing from the code snippet shown above.  If you have modified that code snippet to add it, perhaps you can update it above.